# HighChart XAxes Category

Tags: highcharts

I want to draw line graph with highchart. I have some values from database.
like : `Array ( [0] => Array ( [sum] => 1820 [ay] => October ) [1] => Array ( [sum] => 3144 [ay] => November )`

I have two vaues for two months(October and November)

my script is:

```
 xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },
```

When I want to draw graph.Its looks like in picture.
[image]
Its showing January and February. How can change it by my value.

Answer (score 0):

Array format make an array with just month.

```
foreach($data5 as $mon)
{
$zzz .="'".$mon['ay']."',";
}
```

and script will be:

```
 xAxis: {
            categories: [<?php echo $zzz; ?>]
        },
```